# Default constructor being called by derived class

Tags: c++

Suppose I am implementing a game of two-player chess. Here is a shortened version of my implementation for simplicity's sake, omitting any irrelevant details. I have a class `Piece` from which the various pieces are derived. In this example I am only including the `King` piece.

```
extern enum piece_t;
extern enum color_t;
class Piece
{
public:
    Piece() {}
    Piece(piece_t t, char r, color_t c)
        : type(t), representation(r), color(white)
        {}

    char getRepresentation()
        { return representation; }
protected:
    piece_t type;
    color_t color;
    char representation;
};

class King : public Piece
{
public:
    King() {}
    King(color_t color) { Piece(K,'K',color); }
};
```

In another class, `Board` I define a member to instantiate `King`

```
class Board
{
public:
    Board() { king = King(white); }
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, const Board&);
private:
    King king;
};
```

Here is an example of main:

```
int main(void)
{
    Board game;
    std::cout << game;
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that the default constructor is being called. I know this is happening because my `king` object is being initialized with garbage.

My intention is for `king` to be initialized in `Board`'s constructor:

`Board() { king = King(white); }`

From here I want the constructor from King which takes a `color_t` argument to be called, which will thereby call the constructor from `Piece` like so:

`King(color_t color) { Piece(K, 'K', color); }`

This is not what is happening. The default constructor (of either `King` or `Piece` or both) is being called. Is `king`'s default constructor called when it is declared in the private field of `Board`? If this is the case, how do I alter the code so that `king` calls the appropriate constructor?

Comment: `Piece(K,'K',color);` creates a temporary object. You need to use the mem-initializer-list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have the wrong syntax (which is legal, but doesn't do what you think). You need to call the base class constructor in the *initializaton list*:

```
King(color_t color) : Piece(K,'K',color) {}
```

By the time you get into a constructor's body, all base classes and data members have already been initialized. If you don't initialize them explicitly, they get default initialized (which means calling the default constructor in the case fo the base class).

In your code, you were instantiating a local, anonymous `Piece` object.

Comment: "wrong" = does something different than intended

Comment: @dyp wrong in the context of what OP intends the code to do :)

Comment: Thank you +1; It solved my problem. Could you give me a brief explanation of why it must be called from the initialization list instead of the constructor body?

Comment: the syntax was just wrong

Comment: @TylerGaona The explanation is in my answer.